# Method override for expressJS not working for PUT hidden method HTML FORM

Tags: mongodb, express, middleware, overriding

Using express and mongoose/mongo to create a todo app. Domain model: Authors have reminders.

In my `app.js`:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var methodOverride = require('method-override')
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))
```

my form using handlebars in `views/authors/edit.hbs`:

```
<h2>Edit {{name}}</h2>
<form action="/authors/{{_id}}" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

My routing for the edit view and put request to update author:

```
app.get("/authors/:id/edit", function(req, res){
  AuthorModel.findById(req.params.id, function(err, docs){
    res.render("authors/edit", docs)
  })
})

app.put("/authors/:id", function(req, res){
  console.log("updating")
  AuthorModel.findById(req.params.id, function(err, docs){
    docs.name = req.body.name
    docs.save(function(err){
      if(!err){
        res.redirect("authors/" + req.params.id)
      }
    })
  })
})
```

When I inspect the elements in the dev tools I see everything I need to see, but when I go to submit, gives me error CANNOT POST. Create functionality works fine, so my first thought is the method override isn't working. If I change put to POST, everything works great.

If it helps, link to the repo that contains this [app](https://github.com/andrewsunglaekim/reminders_mongo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the documentation, there are two common ways to override the method:

- using [a header](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override#override-using-a-header);
- using a [query string parameter](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override#override-using-a-query-value);

You're using the "old" method of specifying a form variable, which you can still use, but this requires [custom logic](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override#custom-logic) on the server side.

It seems to me that the easiest way for you to fix this is to use the query string parameter:

```
<form action="/authors/{{_id}}?_method=put" method="post">
```

Comment: I tried doing the query string method and got a weird result, let me try to recreate.

Comment: `Cannot POST /authors/565a5a74681a4a99ab7067a9?_method=put` is the error i receive

Comment: What if the article to be edited, ends with a "?" or "!"  ? That way, method override doesn't work . Do you know any work-around?